# Compute how much the one percent wealthier concentrates using survey data

Tags: r, survey

I would like to compute in R how much the one percent wealthier concentrates. For example, maybe it is the case that the one percent wealthier concentrates 33% of total wealth in the country.

I have a survey dataset with the variables:

- asset: Value of total assets for each individual (row);
- wgt  : Sample weight associated with each individual (row).

What is the best way to compute this concentration measure?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example .

Comment: meh you all are too tough on him.  :)  this question has a pretty straightforward programmatic answer for those of us familiar with the `survey` package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

welcome to SO.  please don't be discouraged by the downvoters, i think your question is perfectly reasonable.  let's say your survey design object is `scf.design`  .. that way, you could try a test case using the [survey of consumer finances](https://github.com/ajdamico/usgsd/tree/master/Survey%20of%20Consumer%20Finances)

```
# compute the cutoff point for the top percentile
y <- coef( svyquantile( ~ asset , scf.design , 0.99 ) )
# for this, you probably don't need the standard error, 
# so immediately just extract the coefficient (the actual number)
# and discard the standard error term by using the `coef` function
# around the `svyquantile` call

# create a new flag in your survey design object
# that's a 1 if the individual is in the top percentile
# and a 0 for everybody else
scf.design <- update( scf.design , onepct = as.numeric( asset > y ) )

# calculate the aggregate of all assets
# held by the top percentile
# and also held by everybody else
svyby( ~asset , ~onepct , scf.design , svytotal )

# or, if you like, calculate them separately
svytotal( ~asset , subset( scf.design , onepct == 1 ) )

svytotal( ~asset , subset( scf.design , onepct == 0 ) )

# and divide each of those numbers by all assets
# held by everybody
svytotal( ~asset , scf.design )
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony! I am the guy who sent you an email about the Gini coefficient with the SCF. I will try your solution.